# Merge lines by one field

Tags: linux, awk, merge

I have a file like this:

```
readA    chr1    229665946 229666155 +  ABCB10  NM_012089   exon6
readA    chr1    229667383 229667478 +  ABCB10  NM_012089   exon7
readA    chr1    229675203 229675338 +  ABCB10  NM_012089   exon8
readB    chr2    229675000 229675888 +  KGB09   NM_022158   exon2
```

and I want to merge it by first column like this:

```
readA    chr1    229665946 229675338 +  ABCB10  NM_012089   exon6,exon7,exon8
readB    chr2    229675000 229675888 +  KGB09   NM_022158   exon2
```

So the first column and chromosome position are merged, I tried to solved this by awk or bedtool merge but failed. Is anyone can help me ? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to SO, when you say you tried something to fix, please do add that attempt to your post too in code tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following may help you on same.

```
awk '{a[$1]=a[$1]?a[$1] OFS $NF:$0} END{for(i in a){print a[i]}}' OFS=,   Input_file
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't know how to use array in awk, so at first I tried to split file into several tmp file then sort, grep etc. But this way is apparently faster!  However, except for combining the last column by comma, I also want to merge the chromosome region. I ran your code, but the chromosome region was not merged..

Comment: @Charlie, which one is chromosome field, please confirm once?

Comment: for each line, $3 is start point of chromosome region and $4 is stop point. In this case, I want to print: readA  chr1 line_1_start line_3_end +  ABCB10  NM_012089   exon6,exon7,exon8